# simple scala socket program - talks to one client only?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a very simple scala socket program that will "echo" out any input it recieves from multiple clients

This program does work but only for a single client.  I think this is because execution is always in `while(true)` loop

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
import scala.io._


//println(util.Properties.versionString)

val server = new ServerSocket(9999)
println("initialized server")
val client = server.accept

while(true){

val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream)).readLine
val out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream)

println("Server received:" + in) // print out the input message
out.println("Message received")
out.flush


}
```

I've tried

making this modification

```
while(true){

    val client = server.accept

    val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream)).readLine
    val out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream)
    println("Server received:" + in)  

    }
```

But this does'nt work beyond "echo"ing out a single message

I'd like multiple clients to connect to the socket and constantly receive the output of whatever they type in

Comment: I think you should use the second option, but make the code after `accept` be part of a `Future` code block with other loop.

Comment: @GáborBakos Could you please add a code snippet. this would help me as well.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should accept the connection and create a new `Future` for each client. Beware that the implicit global `ExecutionContext` might be limited, you might need to find a different one that better fits your use cases.

You can use Scala async if you need more complex tasks with futures, but I think this is probably fine.

Disclaimer, I have not tried this, but something similar might work (based on your code and [the docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)):

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
...

while(true){
    val client = server.accept
    Future {
        val inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream))
        val out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream)
        do {
            val in = inReader.readLine
            println("Server received:" + in)
        } while (true/*or a better condition to close the connection */)
        client.close
    }
}
```

Comment: @wolfgang I have updated the code a bit. I like this way better. Maybe the `in` could be a `var` outside the inner loop, so its value could be used in the `do`-`while` condition.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find an example for the scala language:

```
[http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/55][1]
```

And this is also a good example from scala twitter school, that works with java libraries:

import java.net.{Socket, ServerSocket}
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, ExecutorService}
import java.util.Date

```
class NetworkService(port: Int, poolSize: Int) extends Runnable {
  val serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)

  def run() {
    while (true) {
      // This will block until a connection comes in.
      val socket = serverSocket.accept()
      (new Handler(socket)).run()
    }
  }
}

class Handler(socket: Socket) extends Runnable {
  def message = (Thread.currentThread.getName() + "\n").getBytes

  def run() {
    socket.getOutputStream.write(message)
    socket.getOutputStream.close()
  }
}

(new NetworkService(2020, 2)).run
```

Comment: Here http://pastebin.com/XQYeUXuv , i put a `while(true)` loop inside `Handler.run` and this does'nt really talk to multiple clients when `telnet`(ed) from multiple terminals

Comment: Your code looks like it should be multithreaded, which it isn't. Maybe you want to fix that, or at least remove that deception? (And add the imports into the code block)